# How can I minimise the time to get a new UK passport?

Tags: passports, uk-citizens

I am a UK citizen. I have lost my passport and planned to travel by Eurostar from London to Paris in five days' time. The quoted time for a fast-track replacement passport is "within 1 week" of an appointment.

1. When can I book the appointment? I.e., could I book one at 9am this morning, for midday? Could I book one for the evening (after 5pm) or would I have to wait until the next working day?
2. How likely is it that the new passport could arrive within less than a week? If I collect in person rather than it being posted, could I minimise the time to get one?
3. Is there any other way to minimise the time? E.g. if I have a scan of my old passport, and/or it was found by the police and returned to the passport office and cancelled? If I pay a premium?

Comment: Call the passport advice line: https://www.gov.uk/passport-advice-line perhaps one of the service centres is quicker than another. I used the one at Peterborough to get a same day passport, but unfortunately you're not eligible for that with a lost passport.

Answer (score 10):

My wife lost her British passport earlier this month. Here's the basic timeline...

```
3 July (Sunday): discovered the passport was lost
3 July (Sunday): filled out the lost passport form on the net
4 July (Monday): filed paperwork at the post office
6 July (Wednesday):  received call from the passport office to schedule an appointment
11 July (Monday): attended in-person interview at the passport office (Victoria)
16 July (Saturday): delivery service dropped off new passport at our residence
```

Despite not being eligible for the 'premium service' we basically paid for every upgrade available (we are headed off to Russia in a few days for a brief holiday). The total outlay was GBP 106.  Plus photos. Plus travel to Victoria.

Based on this experience I have it in mind that the minimum time span to replace a lost passport from discovery to possession is 14 days *for Brits who can make it to Victoria*.

Note: "Victoria" = "[HM Passport Office, London Victoria](http://www.passports-office.co.uk/london_passport_office_directions.asp)"